# reshape r dataframe to wide format

Tags: r, reshape

Is there a simple way to reshape this

```
id  date
A   Jan 2012
B   Jan 2012
C   Jan 2012
A   Feb 2012
B   Feb 2012
A   Mar 2012
B   MAr 2012
```

in

```
id  Jan 2012    Feb 2012    Mar 2012
A   T           T           T
B   T           T           T
C   T           F           F
```

`dcast` and `reshape` requires a aggregate function that I don't think I need (?)

Comment: Um. `table(mydf)` where your object is called "mydf"?

Comment: @AnandaMahto +1 I added that in - but you mean `table(mydf) > 0` ?

Comment: @SimonO101, `TRUE` evaluates to "1" and `FALSE` to "0", so I don't think that's entirely necessary.

Comment: @AnandaMahto yes very true in this case. If there were more than one entry for any combination you would need it - I put that it because of the data I used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dcast` as you suggest...

```
#  Please provide reproducible data next time!
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame( id = rep(c("A","B","C"),3 ), date = sample( month.name[1:3] , 9 , repl = TRUE ) , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
#  id     date
#1  A  January
#2  B    March
#3  C February
#4  A    March
#5  B    March
#6  C  January
#7  A February
#8  B    March
#9  C February

require( reshape2 )
dcast( dt , id ~ date  , fun = function(x) length(x) > 0 , fill = FALSE )
#  id February January March
#1  A     TRUE    TRUE  TRUE
#2  B    FALSE   FALSE  TRUE
#3  C     TRUE    TRUE FALSE
```

Or just `table` as **@AnandaMahto** suggets...

```
table(dt) > 0
#   date
#id  February January March
#  A     TRUE    TRUE  TRUE
#  B    FALSE   FALSE  TRUE
#  C     TRUE    TRUE FALSE
```

Which is certianly syntactically easier!!

Comment: with `dcast` says `using date as value column: use values.var to override` and then crushes! it's the third time in a row...

Comment: @nigmastar how big is your data and how many combinations are there?

Comment: is a `data.table` of ca 6.5M rows and 400K unique ids. But it's one the smallest I've got. I probably got too used to `data.table` that any other package seems crap now :-)

Comment: I think we need a `data.table` solution then.

Comment: possibly, or maybe I need to change the function next in the "stack" (which needs the wide format) into another which can work directly with the long one.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work great for what you are looking for:

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B"), date = c("2012-01", "2012-01", "2012-01", "2012-02", "2012-02", "2012-03", "2012-03"))
df$date <- as.yearmon(df$date)

result <- with(df, tapply(date, list(id, date), length))
result[is.na(result)] <- 0
result <- (result == 1)
```

You get:

```
   Jan 2012 Feb 2012 Mar 2012
 A     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
 B     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE
 C     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
```

Comment: No `reshape`, no `dcast`!

Comment: Thanks. I do use zoo for its yearmon class, but I gotta get rid of it cause it's a ridicusly slow with "big" data.

Comment: @nigmastar The `zoo` library here was just used to format my test dataframe to look like yours. The other lines of code don't require `zoo`

Comment: I know, I wasn't critic to your answer because of that. I meant " oh cool!, I use zoo too! But unfortunately ... etc etc"

Comment: Hehe oh I get it :) Are you looking to replace the `as.yearmon` function? Also, for big data, `xts` would be a better option that `zoo`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I mainly use that function from zoo (and sometimes `as.yearqtr`). Thanks! I'll give it a try.